# Не получается запустить сервер на 445 порт(Linux)

Tags: python, linux, сервер

Пытаюсь использовать эксплойт с данной [ссылки](https://krbtgt.pw/smbv3-null-pointer-dereference-vulnerability/).

Проблема в том, что PoC не запускается на 445 порту (данный порт обычно используется SBM протоколом).

Как решить данную проблему? Я так думаю, что он просто занят или запрещен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для номеров портов до тысячи требуется root

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на текст "Доступ запрещен". Порты с низкими портами могут занять только процессы запускаемые от имени привелегированных польователей

Comment: или со специальным мандатом, но для скриптов это не применимо...